# file Encoding to UTF-8

Tags: java

help to solve the problem here is the script searches the internet and saves, but he keeps them with the wrong encoding, and to UTP-8, here's where you can insert in the program coding, insert please (when the page is saved, its content is also in mangled characters)

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class url{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URL PageUrl;
            URLConnection GetConn = null;
            GetConn = null;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C:\\test\\url.txt")); 
            String htmlPage;
            while (sc.hasNext()){
                htmlPage = sc.nextLine();
                PageUrl = new URL(htmlPage);
                GetConn = PageUrl.openConnection();
                GetConn.connect();
                // establish connection:
                Scanner scUrl = new Scanner(GetConn.getInputStream());

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                while(scUrl.hasNext()){
                    sb.append(scUrl.nextLine());
                }
                scUrl.close();

                String htmlFileName = ("C:\\test\\1\\"+title(sb.toString())+".html");
                FileWriter FWriter = new FileWriter(htmlFileName);
                BufferedWriter BWriter = new BufferedWriter(FWriter);

                BWriter.write(sb.toString());
                BWriter.close();
            }// end try
            sc.close();
        }
        catch (IOException io) {
            System.out.println(io);
        }
    }

    private static String title(String str){

        return str.substring(str.indexOf("title>")+6, str.indexOf("</title>"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add on the answer of @Brian Agnew - 
It should be as far as I know:

```
new Scanner(GetConn.getInputStream(),"UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 2):

This

```
new Scanner(GetConn.getInputStream());
```

gets an input stream (byte-oriented) from your web page. But it's using the default encoding for your JVM and you're not looking at the encoding of the actual page itself.

I would perhaps use a library like [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) to decode/parse the HTML correctly and then ask it for the page title. The code above is potentially quite fragile.

Comment: I have no need to program files encoded in UTF-8 remained